# Changing a method into my main method

Tags: java, netbeans-8

So I am new to java and I am practicing converting public static method into my main method. This is my first attempt and I am kind of lost. I was wondering if someone could show me how and maybe I can figure it out. Here is the current method I am working with.

```
   public static int getVowel(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (isVowel(ch)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Hopefully I described everything correctly. I am new to java and I am still figuring out all the terms.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting into my main method" as that doesn't parse for me? Wouldn't you rather want to simply call this method from inside of your main method when required? Please clarify your problem and requirements for us. Don't assume that we know what you're trying to achieve just yet.

Comment: Please describe to us plainly what you hope to achieve. You may not be familiar with all the technical terms, but you must have some understanding of a goal in mind. Then we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int vowel;
    // ==== getVowel ==== 
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < "Programming is fun".length(); i++) {
        char ch = Character.toUpperCase("Programming is fun".charAt(i));
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    vowel = count;

    int consonant;
    // ==== getConsonant ==== 
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < "Programming is fun".length(); i++) {
        char ch = Character.toUpperCase("Programming is fun".charAt(i));
        if (!(ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') && ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    consonant = count;

    System.out.println(vowel + " " + consonant);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for not describing everything correctly. Here is the code I am working with.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int vowel = getVowel("Programming is fun");
    int consonant = getConsonants("Programming is fun");
    System.out.println(vowel + " " + consonant);
}

public static int getConsonants(String s) {
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (isConsonant(ch)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static int getVowel(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (isVowel(ch)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
    return ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U';
}

public static boolean isConsonant(char ch) {
    return !isVowel(ch) && ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z';
}
```

}

I do not want to call other methods into my main method. I only want the main method in this code. I'm trying to learn how to rewrite code in different ways for practice. Hopefully I made things a little bit more clear.

Comment: That's pretty good code. Why do you want to ruin it by getting rid of the methods? You could put everything in one massive `main` method, but why?

Comment: Just for practice. I found this code online and I want to be able to create methods and deconstruct methods.